# The best way to write a dictionary to a CSV file when the values are 2d lists?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, export-to-csv

I have the following dictionary

```
dict = {5: [ [a00, a01, ..., a0n], [a10, a11, ..., a1n], ... ],
        6: [ [b00, b01, ..., b0n], [b10, b11, ..., b1n], ... ],
        7: [ [c00, c01, ..., c0n], [c10, c11, ..., c1n], ... ],               
        8: etcetera }
```

All the 2d lists have the same amount of columns, but different amount of rows.

What is the best way to write this to a csv file. Currently I use

```
w = csv.writer(open("python_output.csv", "w"))
for key, val in dict.items():
    w.writerow([key, val])
```

But this doesn't work, because the entire 2d list gets put in one cell in the CSV file.

Comment: I think you wanted [`writerows`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `writerows` method available for `csv.writer`

```
import csv
dict1 = {5: [['a00', 'a01', 'a0n'], ['a10', 'a11', 'a1n'], ['a20', 'a21', 'a2n']], 6: [['b00', 'b01', 'b0n'], ['b10', 'b11', 'b1n'], ['b20', 'b21', 'b2n']], 7: [['c00', 'c01', 'c0n'], ['c10', 'c11', 'c1n'], ['c20', 'c21', 'c2n']], 8: [['d00', 'd01', 'd0n'], ['d10', 'd11', 'd1n'], ['d20', 'd21', 'd2n']]}
rows = [[k]+l for k,v in dict1.items() for l in v]
with open('tmp.txt', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(rows)
```

**Output**

```
5,a00,a01,a0n
5,a10,a11,a1n
5,a20,a21,a2n
6,b00,b01,b0n
6,b10,b11,b1n
6,b20,b21,b2n
7,c00,c01,c0n
7,c10,c11,c1n
7,c20,c21,c2n
8,d00,d01,d0n
8,d10,d11,d1n
8,d20,d21,d2n
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

[Itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) is your friend:

```
import itertools

w = csv.writer(open("python_output.csv", "w"))
for key, val in idict.items():
    w.writerow([key, *itertools.chain(*val)])
```

The output file content then is:

```
5,a00,a01,a0n,a10,a11,a1n
6,b00,b01,b0n,b10,b11,b1n
7,c00,c01,c0n,c10,c11,c1n
```

Comment: Hi phngs, thank you for your reply. I tried, but it doesn't work. I get: 5, <itertools.chain object at 0x7f2650909150>, etc.

Comment: You are right, I changed the answer accordingly. It is necessary to unpack the values with * and to convert the iterator to a list first.

Comment: I get the following error: `w.writerow([key, *list(itertools.chain(*val))])
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: I would try to solve the syntax error myself, but this syntax is going over my head ;)

Comment: I have no idea why it does not work for you. But looking at the accepted answer, this is anyway not what you wanted, as it outputs every dict entry in one row.

Comment: Maybe because I'm using a different python version? I'm not sure, but thanks for your help anyway

Comment: Ok, my bad again, is was one parenthesis too much. Changed the answer again as I do not like non-working stuff hanging around ;)

Comment: phngs, I will try your version later tonight if I have time. Otherwise I'll look at it tomorrow, and let you know. Thanks for your help :)